# creating a php user registration page, getting a SQL error

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a registration page. It can be accessed via btcbidder.com/register

Currently, when I try to register an account, i get the error :

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@gmail.com,
>   87e1bdad537ee992ee550a9b8f555530e5ad41a5ce4848ed67dea21c63f633ee3940'
>   at line 1
>
> INSERT into tbl_user VALUES (NULL, lmfsthefounder,
>   lmfsthefounder@gmail.com,
>   87e1bdad537ee992ee550a9b8f555530e5ad41a5ce4848ed67dea21c63f633ee3940149e852ff69e6555f817485e641e17edb0c0bf51296a276206cab0cd88ef,
>   658b851a9655567ca, NULL, NULL);
>
> Filename:
>   /home/content/61/11420661/html/btcbidder.com/controllers/register.php
>
> Line Number: 53

The code I am using (outside the form) is:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])){

            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $salt = generate_salt();
            $pwhash = hash_password($salt . $_POST['password']);

            //$q = sprintf('INSERT into tbl_user (username, email, pwhash, salt) VALUES ();');

                if ($this->db->query("INSERT into tbl_user VALUES (NULL, $username, $email, $pwhash, $salt, NULL, NULL);")){
                    echo "<h3> Registration successful</h3><br><br>
                    <p><a href='".site_url()."login'>Click here to log in </a></p>";
                }
            }
```

Just to see, I tried adding this to the database using mysql browser, but as expected it fails there too.

If it helps, here is the table:

```
'user_pk', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'PRI', '', 'auto_increment'
'username', 'varchar(16)', 'NO', 'UNI', '', ''
'email', 'varchar(254)', 'NO', 'UNI', '', ''
'pwhash', 'varchar(256)', 'NO', '', '', ''
'salt', 'varchar(32)', 'NO', '', '', ''
'wallet', 'varchar(64)', 'NO', 'UNI', '', ''
'usertype', 'varchar(10)', 'YES', '', '', ''
```

Is it a problem with the email field? It seems that the error shows right at the @symbol, is that not an allowed character?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a library for this? Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: It doesn't look as if you have any quotes around any of your text fields.

Comment: @Wallter, please note that I am by no means a php developer- I am a java/python programmer, trying to bastardize this project together because the freelancer I had hired didn't complete the job. That said, he had written a register page once, but I never got access to that before he quit. I do, however, have the login script, so I am trying to match the stuff together.

Comment: @JayBlanchard that sure was the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with your insert values. You should insert username, email, pwhash, salt, wallet and usertype as STRING, I mean, surrounded with quotes.

Comment: see above answer, I needed the quotes.